# Django Modal save() function not implemented, using google app engine dev server and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine

First of all, I want to clarify that I searched everywhere on google & stackoverflow and I couldn't find the solution to the problem I'm having, so this post might seem like a repost but it is not.

Background Info: I am using Django with mysql as the backend, I'm trying to deploy django app onto google app engine with cloud sql instance enabled.

**Problem:**
I am currently testing the app on google app engine dev. server, the problem I'm having is 
that I am trying to upload a video file and an image file using a form and it doesn't work for some reason. It worked on django inbuilt server.

This is what I what I did so far:

I came to know that images could only be stored in blobs, so without re-inventing the wheel, I quickly downloaded and installed django-filetransfers which I believe uploads file using blobs. I followed the instructions as specified on the website(http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-filetransfers#documentation), it still did not work.

The code snippet looks like as follows:

```
view_url = reverse('myapp.views.myview')
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = MyForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
     form.save_project(request.user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect(view_url)

    upload_url, upload_data = prepare_upload(request, view_url)
    form = MyForm(label_suffix='')
    template_var = {'form': form,
                    'upload_url':upload_url,
                    'upload_data':upload_data}
    return render(request,'mypage.html',template_var)
```

Following function is inside forms.py file under class MyForm:

```
def save_project(self,user,commit=True):
    inst = super(MyForm,self).save(commit=False)
    inst.user = user
    if commit:
        inst.save()
    return inst
```

Straight forward code, nothing complicated. When I run it on google dev server,  it gives an error at inst.save() saying OSERROR,  [Errno 40] Function not implemented and it gets traced to os.makedirs(directory) in "django\core\files\storage.py in _save".

I googled more and came to know google app engine doesn't do writes? What does that even mean and how am I suppose to save the data then?

I've been trying to make my django app work on google dev server since last 2 days, after going through all kinds of hurdles, now I'm stuck at this and its very frustrating. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a precise and clear information on "**how to upload files through forms on gae dev server using django orm since I'm using Mysql"**.

Thanks.

Comment: A lotof other dups in s.o. deal with this. Yes, no filesystem writes in appengine. Its well documented in s.o. and the official guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, Appengine does not permit you to save files to a local disk. You will need to store them somewhere else. You could put them in MySQL or you could save them to a distributed store like Google Blobstore or Cloud Storage. GCS even has the ability to serve the images that you upload so that you don't have to take that traffic yourself. This is very nice in that it completely offloads file upload and file serving traffic from your GAE instances.

Here is a snippet from GAE Blobstore API docs describing how you'd go about delegating all this to the blobstore service:

> The user creates a blob by submitting an HTML form that includes one
>   or more file input fields. Your application calls create_upload_url()
>   to get the destination (action) of this form, passing the function a
>   URL path of a handler in your application. When the user submits the
>   form, the user's browser uploads the specified files directly to the
>   Blobstore. The Blobstore rewrites the user's request and stores the
>   uploaded file data, replacing the uploaded file data with one or more
>   corresponding blob keys, then passes the rewritten request to the
>   handler at the URL path you provided to create_upload_url(). This
>   handler can do additional processing based on the blob key.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob

You can then save a reference (key) to that blog in a field in your SQL table.

If this method isn't suitable for you and you must store the data somewhere else, Django does provide a way for you to override the default file upload handling.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#custom-upload-handlers

But be aware that you will now be streaming all that data through your GAE instance and have to keep in mind any limitations that may have (e.g. memory limits, increased load/cost on your instances ...).

Hope that helps.